# join on multiple/group of entries

Tags: database, google-bigquery

I would like to combine the entries from the two tables below to match `obj` to `class` via `attr`.

I have many objects with different names, dates, and other information in a single table (not shown). Each of these objects can fall into classes based on their attributes. The mapping of objects `obj` to each of their attributes `attr` is in Table A. The mapping of classes `class` to attributes `attr` is in Table B.

I would like to map each object `obj` to its matching class `class` to give the desired output shown in Table C.

In some ways, this seems like a join operation on groups. Is there a way to do this in standard sql and/or with Google BigQuery?

An important point -- both `attr` of a `class` and of an `obj` are not ordered.

Table A:

```
-------------------
|  obj  |  attr   | 
-------------------
|  obj1 |     I   |
|  obj1 |     II  |  
|  obj2 |     I   |
|  obj2 |     II  |
|  obj3 |     I   |
|  obj3 |     II  |  
|  obj3 |     II  |
|  obj4 |     III |
|  obj4 |     I   |
-------------------
```

Table B:

```
-------------------
| attr  |  class  | 
-------------------
|  I    |    A    |
|  II   |    A    |  
|  I    |    B    |
|  III  |    B    |
-------------------
```

Desired output (Table C):

```
-----------------------
|  obj     |  class   | 
-----------------------
|  obj1    |    A     |
|  obj2    |    A     |
|  obj4    |    B     |
-----------------------
```

(Note that `obj3` doesn't fall into `class` `A` because it has an additional `II` `attr`.)

Comment: I don't understand the algorithm still. Maybe someone else will be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT obj, class FROM (
  SELECT obj, STRING_AGG(attr ORDER BY attr) attr
  FROM `project.dataset.TableA`
  GROUP BY obj
) JOIN (
  SELECT class, STRING_AGG(attr ORDER BY attr) attr
  FROM `project.dataset.TableB`
  GROUP BY class
) USING(attr)
```

You can test / play with it using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.TableA` AS (
  SELECT 'obj1' obj, 'I' attr UNION ALL
  SELECT 'obj1', 'II' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'obj2', 'I' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'obj2', 'II' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'obj3', 'I' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'obj3', 'II' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'obj3', 'II' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'obj4', 'III' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'obj4', 'I' 
), `project.dataset.TableB` AS (
  SELECT 'I' attr, 'A' class UNION ALL
  SELECT 'II', 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'III', 'B' 
)
SELECT obj, class FROM (
  SELECT obj, STRING_AGG(attr ORDER BY attr) attr
  FROM `project.dataset.TableA`
  GROUP BY obj
) JOIN (
  SELECT class, STRING_AGG(attr ORDER BY attr) attr
  FROM `project.dataset.TableB`
  GROUP BY class
) USING(attr)
```

Output is:

```sql
obj     class    
----    -----
obj1    A    
obj2    A    
obj4    B
```